# Light weight editor that allows file editing through its own FTP client

Tags: windows, ftp, text-editors

I am using Windows and I need a lightweight editor where I can edit files through FTP. The saving feature should be very fast.

I have been using UltraEdit but maybe something better is out there.

I want an actual editor that has FTP feature so that I don't need to download the files

Answer (score 5):

[Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) has an "edit" feature that lets you use the default editor on the file.

Answer (score 4):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is lightweight and has a built in plugin that supports Ftp (goto Plugins menu and and select nppFTP)

Answer (score 3):

Funnily enough I looked into this question when I had the problem, and discovered that Windows's internal client is hard to beat for that feature. e.g. open "My Computer" and FTP to the URL. This was the solution somebody mentioned to a guy that asked it, and it worked for them and for me. Despite what you might ridiculously think, despite what you say, you're always going to need to download the files or you're not going to be able to view them. Windows's internal FTP facility uses notepad. I doubt you even found it to be slow at saving.

Comment: I wonder if IE's FTP is different and lacks the feature? But Window's one has it.